# Track NFT transactions on 0x by fee recipient

Tags: 0x

Is it possible to find NFT sale transactions going through 0x v4 that have fees going to a certain specific address?

When I look at transaction data for the 0x v4 contract on etherscan, it just shows byte code as the input data. I assume this is because of the multiplexer 0x uses but this means I can’t decode the fee recipient.

Anyone know a way to do this or workaround?

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply looking to decode the fee recipient(s) from the transaction data, you should be able to use the ABI from [this file](https://github.com/0xProject/protocol/blob/development/packages/contract-artifacts/artifacts/IZeroEx.json).

Note, however, that e.g. Coinbase if not currently taking a marketplace fee on these transactions, so you wouldn't be able to identify that an order originated from Coinbase based on the fee recipient. For this, we recommend that marketplaces use the high bits of the order nonce field to identify themselves (but no one is doing this yet, to my knowledge). See https://docs.0x.org/nft-support/guides/creating-orders#choosing-a-nonce for details.